# Series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \ln(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, infinite-product

I am trying to determine whether the series 
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \ln\left(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}\right)$ converges or not.

I have tried using a Taylor series of the summand, which gives
$$v_n = -\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n} - \frac{1}{2n} + O\left(\frac{1}{n\sqrt n}\right)$$
whose series does not converge because the first term gives an alternating series, the big-O is absolutely convergent but the middle term is the harmonic series, and is thus equivalent to $-\frac{1}{2}\ln n$.
Thus the series diverges and the partial sum tends to negative infinity.

However, Wolfram Alpha tells me the exponential of the series, the infinite product $\displaystyle\prod_{n=2}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}\right)$ has a nonzero limit, which contradicts that.

Have I been doing something wrong ?

Comment: Maybe you mistyped the Wolfram Alpha input. The series indeed diverges to $-\infty$. Something you definitely did wrong was to write $\frac{1}{2k}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2n}$ in the expansion of $v_n$.

Comment: Well, the product of two consecutive terms of the form $1-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is $1-\frac{1}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}\right)$, and your proof of divergence looks perfectly fine.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Wolfram|Alpha does give [a non-zero limit](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\prod_{n%3D2}^{\infty}\left%281-\frac{%28-1%29^n}{\sqrt%20n}\right%29&dataset=).

Comment: @DanielFischer Whoops. I copied straight over from a sheet of paper where it was $v_k$. Thank you I edited the original post.

Comment: Good, so @joriki's link proves that Wolfram Alpha gives a wrong answer. While that doesn't positively _prove_ that you didn't mistype, we can relegate that to a merely theoretical possibility and conclude that you haven't done anything wrong here. The error is on the other side of the internet connection.

Comment: In fact $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}=(\sqrt2-1)\zeta\left(\frac12\right)$$ and $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k\sqrt{k}}=\zeta\left(\frac32\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha was wrong, and my proof was correct. We indeed have
$$
\prod_{n=2}^\infty \left(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}\right) = 0
$$
as $\displaystyle\sum _{k=2}^n \ln\left(1-\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt k}\right) = -\frac{1}{2}\ln(n) + \mathrm O(1)$ as $n $ approaches infinity.

Comment: interesting path that could have been taken is to take: 


$$\exp\sum_{k=2}^n \ln\left(1-\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt k}\right)) = \prod_{n=2}^{\infty}e^{ln(1-\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt(n)}}$$


Now all one, has to show:

 $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\prod_{n=2}^{N}e^{ln(1-\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt(n)}} = 0$$

Comment: I think this can be done via a Stirling's approximation